# Lazy brainfuck programmer

Tags: code-challenge, brainfuck, code-generation

### Background

Joe is working on his new Brainfuck answer on Codegolf. The algorithm he's using to solve the challenge is a bit complicated, so Joe came up with idea of simplifying his Brainfuck notation to make programming easier and faster.

### The challenge

Let's look at snippet written by Joe a moment ago:

```
0+++++1+++++0[3+0-]+1[3-2+1-]2[1+2-]3[0-3[-]]
```

This program was meant to check for equality of #0 and #1 cells in memory. Your task is to create a preprocessor for Joe, that will replace **single digits** from input with '>' and '<' characters, so the memory pointer will slide to cell specified.

### Input

You may take input from any source - function parameter, standard input, or any other device. The input might be in form of a stream, string, or a byte array.

The input may contain characters from all over the ASCII range, but can't contain brainfuck memory pointer instructions (`<` & `>`).

All the digits you see in the input are expected to be placed here just for your program.

### Output

As Joe didn't write his preprocessor yet, he had to make the code interpretable by hand. That's the result he got:

```
+++++>+++++<[>>>+<<<-]+>[>>-<+<-]>[<+>-]>[<<<->>>[-]]
```

There are pretty much no restrictions on output - if the input has braces unbalanced, just copy them over in unbalanced amount to the output.

### Bonus tasks

If you think the challenge is too boring in current form, you might want to complete these tasks aswell for slight byte count reduction, and more fun obviously:

- Optimize out nonsense related to memory operations, like digits at the end of input or clustered digits (just take the last one) **- 20% of byte amount when completed**
- Minify Brainfuck output (remove clustered `+-`, `><`, non-brainfuck, comments and other kind of stuff) **- 20% of byte amount when completed**

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden by default
- Default I/O rules apply
- Programs are scored by their size in bytes.
- Solving additional tasks reduces the score.
- If anything is unclear, please let me know down in the comments
- Scoring of bonus tasks may increase (but not decrease!) in the future.

### Opening bid - C, 144 bytes

```
p,c,x;void g(v){x=v?'<':'>';if(v<0)v*=-1;while(v--)putchar(x);}main(){while((c=getchar())!=-1)if(isdigit(c)){c-=48;g(c-p);p=c;}else putchar(c);}
```

This program should make pretty much everything clear on the input and output side of this challenge, it doesn't implement any bonus tasks though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellywiki/Code-page)

```
V©_¥®N,$Ø<xµ¹e?ØD)
```

A full program. Assumes (like everyone else has) that no actual Brainfuck evaluation has to be made (no balancing of unbalanced brackets)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/s0Mr4Q0sPrfPTUTk8w6bi0NZDO1PtD89w0fz//7@SgTYIGIJJg2hjbQPdWG3DaGNdI21D3VijaENtI91Y42gDXeNo3dhYJQA)**

#### How?

```
V©_¥®N,$Ø<xµ¹e?ØD) - Main Link: list of characters, s
                 ) - for each character, c, in s:
               ØD  -   digits = "0123456789"
              ?    -   if...
             e     -   ...condition: (c) exists in? (digits)
           µ       -   ...then: monadic link:
    ®              -            recall from register (initially 0) 
   ¥               -            last two links as a dyad i.e. f(c, ®):
V                  -              evaluate (c)
 ©                 -              (copy to the register)
  _                -              subtract (®)  i.e. x = value(c) - register
       $           -            last two links as a monad i.e. f(x):
     N             -              negate (x)
      ,            -              pair with (x)  -> [-x,x]
        Ø<         -            list of characters = "<>"
          x        -            repeat (vectorises) - negatives act like 0
            ¹      -   ...else: identity - i.e. f(c) -> c
                   - implicit (smashing) print
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\d/g,n=>'<>'[+(p<n)].repeat(p<n?n-p:p-n,p=n),p=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCsMgFACPo2Je4mdXojmIdSHGhBZ5Sgy9vq2dxcAw7/AJLV6vegOWPfXD9GZsm69Uc4iJLs99OSc0lqyWOE7risyPm8I9YkOojwo4VYPsJ8F6LNhKTnMuJz0oEXwg/xZOcwGeS6dBcQleOckVeO0EaAfeE8b6Fw)

Comment: This is black magic. I assume there's a closure of some kind over `p`, but I just can't understand this!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 `p` is defined in the global scope and initialized in the 3rd dummy parameter of `replace`, before it starts doing its job.

Comment: Could you use the RegEx (or function) as the initial value for `p` to save a couple of bytes?

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think so. That would fail if the first referenced cell is not \$0\$ and there's no reason why it should always be \$0\$.

Comment: What about `s=>s.replace(p=/\d/g,n=>'<'.repeat(p)+'>'.repeat(p=n))`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```
r\d@Tî< +'>pT=Xn
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clxkQFTuPCArJz5wVD1Ybg&input=IjArKysrKzErKysrKzBbMyswLV0rMVszLTIrMS1dMlsxKzItXTNbMC0zWy1dXSI)

Saved 4 bytes porting a comment by tsh on Arnauld's solution which I've been told results in valid BF output.

```
r\d@Tî< +'>pT=Xn     :Implicit input of string
r                    :Replace
 \d                  :Digits (RegEx /\d/g)
   @                 :Pass each match X through a function
    Tî<              :  T (initially 0) time repeat "<"
        +            :  Append
         '>p         :  Repeat ">"
            T=Xn     :    Convert X to an integer and assign it to T for the next match
```

Comment: Second one is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 48 bytes

```perl6
{$!=0;S:g{\d}=['<','>'][$/>$!]x abs +$!-($!=$/)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcq7CsJAEEDRX5mFwVXGIfsAC83mJyzHKSIamwRCFiEh5NvXxy1Odcfn1J/KsMCug1RWNMldrufXentsSWxtj7axKlg1aHSG9p6B0PD@@2F12EpuF@gg9@9pLI5@@b9OIjlW8hI5kGcN4imwRnEchVU/)

Substitutes all digits with the appropriate character repeated the difference between the previous amount of times

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.6, <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>83</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```
p=0
for s in input():
 try:a=int(s)-p;s='>'*a+'<'*-a;p+=a
 except:0
 print(s)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsMgEADvfoU3kywLq95M7Y8sHqSkNBezqIXm6@1rGOY0cvbHUfwYEkndj6qb3stHefZpDkr3eoYc99KnNqOsLZqrWTKYi1kwrwIxK729bpv0QEpL/Z9jEHyxvxJ7IExg2aMDi8mxBYfJM6FnTOkN)

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for -2 bytes.

---

Old version 90 bytes:

```
p=0
for s in input():
 if '/'<s<':':a=int(s);print('>'*(a-p)+'<'*(p-a));p=a
 else:print(s)
```

Thanks to @EmbodimentofIgnorance for -3 bytes.

Comment: I don't think this would work if the input had a multidigit number

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance The spec says _single digits_.

Comment: `'/'<s<':'` instead of `46<ord(s)<58`

Comment: Save two [by avoiding two `print`s](https://tio.run/##JYrLCsMgEADvfoU3kywLq95M7Y8sHqSkNBezqIXm6@1rGOY0cvbHUfwYEkndj6qb3stHefZpDkr3eoYc99KnNqOsLZqrWTKYi1kwrwIxK729bpv0QEpL/Z9jEHyxvxJ7IExg2aMDi8mxBYfJM6FnTOkN)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
εDdi®α„><®y©@è×]J¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FaXlMxD685tfNQwz87m0LrKQysdDq84PD3W69Cy//8NtEHAEEwaRBtrG@jGahtGG@saaRvqxhpFG2ob6cYaRxvoGkfrxsb@19XNy9fNSayqBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>103</s> 99 bytes

```cs
x=>{int i=48;foreach(var g in x)Write(g<58&g>47?new string(g-i<0?'>':'<',Math.Abs(i-(i=g))):g+"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu7CoMwFIDhvU8RHGpCekq8lIpGxQfo3CFksEHjWSKY0Aqlz25v//Bvn/FgPG6dCTg76cOCzjZjva1180QXCNZ5UY3zMvRmovd@IZagIyu7LhgGauWp2NsmP7dueJC/phZQijZu4jKW8eHSh@nY3TxFoFhbxlhpeRSx6rVVu5FGgn9Lfhcq4wI0T1QGKU9ApyrhKehMCcgUaP1h2xs)

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYy9DoIwGAB3n4IwSJv6kRYwEkpLeABnh6aDEqjfUhPaRIzx2fHvhtvuhgBDwLUfIt58G@KM3ulJrYvST/QxQVXVcsl7/yBO6dOMcSSu3ddbp6tD58d78m@IA2x5l@msydpsdzzHa95fAkEgqByltHEsTSmG5HOl8rXKzURSzr6In7kpGQfLhCmhYAJsYQQrwJaGQ2nA2pTK9Q0 "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") by rewriting a single-statement foreach loop into LINQ. This might be possible to improve with Aggregate, but I can't so far.

Comment: Suggest `g<i` instead of `g-i<0`

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 27 bytes

```
\d(\D*)
$*>$1$&$*<
+`<>|<$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcQxCoAwDADAve8Iog2BpFlLJ3@RBhR0cHEQR/8e0Rvu2u/jXCP6NvY5TwlyA4EBck241PZUSBGMH/lnU2RyFFMqKOTFBAu5GpMaub8) Explanation:

```
\d(\D*)
```

Match a digit and then all intervening non-digits.

```
$*>$1$&$*<
```

Slide the memory pointer to the desired cell, then after the intervening code, slide it back to the initial cell.

```
+`<>|<$
```

Cancel out any overlapping slides and delete any trailing slides.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 34 bytes

```
VzI}N."09IÒ"p*\<Zp*\>KsN=ZK.?pN)
```

With unprintable string `\x96\x02` between `."09I` and `Ò`

Explained:

```
Vz                                  # For N in input
  I}N."09IÒ"                        # If N is in the packed string 1234567890
               p*\<Z                # Print Z * "<"
                    p*\>KsN         # K = int(N) and print ">" * K
                           =ZK      # Z = K
                              .?pN) # Else print N
```